# A,B,C,D,E - How can I get "D" with regex? The fourth position of mached result?

Tags: regex

A,B,C,D,E - How can I get "D" with regex? The fourth position of mached result?

I can't set "C,(.*),E" because C and E have dynamic values.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This captures D in group 2:

```
([^,]+,){3}([^,]+),
```

Comment: Why not anchor it, otherwise it also catches E?

Comment: @Yuriy true, but I didn't know whether String was supposed to be matched within a larger String. I've added a comma, that should have the same effect.

Comment: Not sure if it matters to the OP, but with the comma, it will match E in : `A,B,C,D,E,F`.

Comment: I want to get a part of the dynamic string. If I got a string like this:
A,B,C,D,E,F,G

Your regex won't works.

Answer (score 0):

`([A-Z],){3}(A-Z),.*` should work, if you replace A-Z with the actual character classes used (or `[^,]` like Sean used above, which matches everything but a comma).

Better to tokenize based on a comma and grab the fourth result, though (assuming the language you're using supports it).